# Security aspects of second-level domains like .co.uk

Tags: security, dns, xss, subdomain

What are the security aspects of second-level domains like `.co.uk`?

Especially, when it comes to cross-site scripting and cookies stealing.
Many of basic security mechanisms on client rely on different 2nd-level comain names.
Does a developer keep special attention when developing for e.g. `foo.co.uk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers are using a list of effective TLDs, instead of relying only on the level of the domain, for things such as allowing sites to set a cookie.

See http://publicsuffix.org/list/ . As seen [here](http://publicsuffix.org/learn/), this is used by Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: I still wonder about MSIE, but I guess MSFT keeps it's own similar list.